# CentOS7 LXC Container shell access on Ubuntu 17.04 Host

Tags: centos7, lxc, containers, ubuntu-17.04, lxd

I know this is probably google skills deficiency on my behalf but for the love of god I cant shell into a CentOS 7 container on an Ubuntu 17.04 host.

```
user@ubuntu1704:~$ lxc shell centos7
user@ubuntu1704:~$
```

absolutely nothing happens ... no error and I cant find a way to specify login user and password.

Here is how I launched the container

```
lxc launch images:centos/7/amd64 centos7
```

it downloaded the image and launched it. info shows all is fine and has correct ip and everything. By default ssh connections refused (SELinux)

Please help!! very stuck!! Thanks alot !!

Comment: Have you tried `lxc attach --name centos7` or `lxc-attach --name centos7`?

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

- For CentOS images:`lxc exec my-container -- bash`
- For Ubuntu images: `lxc shell my-container`, or
- For Ubuntu images:  `lxc exec my-container -- sudo --login --user username`